# PIC memory addressing not in HEX?

Tags: pic

why are pic memory address not in hexadecimal, I am reading the text book programming 8 bit Pic micro controllers in c By Martin P bates, the memory address start at 000h and go on 001h 002h 003h and so on...

From my C experience I was expecting Hex addressing why is this type of addressing used?

Comment: Can you indicate what exactly makes you think this is not hex?

Comment: Hex 0-9 and A-F I don't know where the H comes from 000h 0001h, I should say from my X86 ASM experience, I use Hex addressing in GDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This form is only one of the many ways of written representation for hexadecimals numbers. It isn't valid in C ANSI.

The `h` at the end is more readable for those that isn't yet familiar with C or any other language way of hex representation.

As a curiosity, Wikipedia lists a lot of ways of written representations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Written_representation).